# Error bars in plot_ly

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I'm creating a simple plot with `plot_ly` and come to a strange behaviour when using error bars. I have tried the example [here](https://plot.ly/r/error-bars/), but even the official manual is wrong (in my opinion). Here an MWE:

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(
      x = 1:3,
      y = c(7,5,9),
      sd = c(0.2, 0.1, 0.7))

plot_ly(df,
        x = ~x,
       error_y = list(value = ~sd)) %>%
  add_markers(y = ~y)
```

The result is not the expected plot, because the errorbars are always 10% of the value, even in the official examples (see link above). It's obvious that the errorbar are much higher than the given ones in `df`. The error are always 10 % of the original value.

[image]

I tried different approaches, e.g. `error_y = list(value = ~sd, type = "data"))` (seen [here](https://rpubs.com/chelsea/68601)), but nothing worked.

I'm thankful for every hint to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the Plotly team has forgotten to update its own examples. The [correct syntax](http://rpubs.com/chelsea/68601) for getting error bars in R Plotly is

```
error_y = list(array=~sd)
```

### [image]

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 3),
  y = c(7, 5, 3),
  sd = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.8))

plot_ly(df,
        x = ~x,
        y = ~y,
        error_y = list(array=~sd),
        type='scatter')
```